# How can I fix relocation error of libc.so.6?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, i386

When I run a script, I get this error:

> relocation error: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: symbol
>   _dl_find_dso_for_object, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux.so.2 with link time reference

I use ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You are a good linuxer, they are the crown of the creation. Sad, that I had to reformat your question and not you did it from yourself. [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) you find a checklist, what is to watch next time.

Comment: Btw, I probably know the answer to your question, but you didn't give enough info. From this is only visible, that there is some incompatibility between your linker and libc. You didn't even mention, if it is a bash script or what. Give a lot of more details and I will be back to help.

Comment: have you even tried to google?

Comment: linker libraries are messed up, perhaps upgraded, or moved to another computer? anyway, this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47115598/2685239